# rank and degree of vector bundle after push-forward or pull-back

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, pullback, pushforward

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic $p >0$, $X$  a smooth projective curve of genus $g \geqslant 2$ over $k$, and $\mathscr{E}$  a vector bundle (or locally free sheaf) on $X$ of rank $n$.

We define the **degree** of $\mathscr{E}$ to be the degree of the divisor associated to the line bundle $\det (\mathscr{E})$, which is the $n$-th exterior of $\mathscr{E}$.

And let $F:X \to X$ be the absolute (or relative) Frobenius morphism of $X$ ( $F_{\#}: \mathscr{O}_X \to \mathscr{O}_X$ is the $p$-th power of the structure sheaf). We denote the push-forward (resp. pull-back) of $\mathscr{E}$ by $F_*\mathscr{E}$ (resp.$F^*\mathscr{E}$).

**My Question**: What is the **rank** and **degree** of $F_*\mathscr{E}$ and $F^*\mathscr{E}$?

I think $\deg (F_*\mathscr{E}) = \deg(\mathscr{E}) +\operatorname{rank}(\mathscr{E})\cdot(p-1)(g-1)$ and $\deg(F^*\mathscr{E}) = p\cdot\deg(\mathscr{E})$. Is that right?

About the rank of $F_*\mathscr{E}$ , I have seen someone said that $\operatorname{rank}(F_*\mathscr{E}) = pn$ , but I don't know how to prove it. And I have no idea about $\operatorname{rank}(F^*\mathscr{E})$.

I appreciate any kind of help!

Sorry  if it is an obvious thing, please just give me a reference paper. Thx!

Comment: If $f:X\to Y$ is a finite map of smooth varieties and $E$ a rank $n$ vector bundle on $X$, then $f_*E$ is a rank $n\cdot\deg f$ vector bundle on $Y$. Similarly, if $f:X\to Y$ is any morphism, and $E$ a rank $n$ bundle on $Y$, then $f^*E$ is a rank $n$ bundle on $X$.

Comment: @Mohan that looks like an answer to me - would you care to record it below?

Comment: @KReiser It only partially answers, since degree statements are not mentioned, though the OP seems to know them, but all the same asks this.

Comment: @Mohan oops, you're right - I misread their post.